# Heat equation that depends on the viscousity constant $\epsilon$

Tags: partial-differential-equations, heat-equation

I want to solve the following heat equation, for $\epsilon>0$:

$$\begin{cases}
      u_t-\epsilon u_{xx}=0 & x<0,\; t\in \mathbb{R^{+*}} \\
      u(0,x)= e^{-\frac{-x}{2\epsilon}}       & x<0 \\
      u(t,0)=1 & t\in \mathbb{R^{+*}} 
\end{cases}$$
And I wanna make sure is the explicit solution is:

$$u(t,x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{4t\epsilon}}\int_{\mathbb{R^{-}}}u(0,s)e^{\frac{(x-s)^2}{4\epsilon}}ds $$

Comment: It seems that your $u$ does not satisfy $u(t, 0) = 1$.

Comment: Well you're right! and that's my question, because the fundamental solution is often given when the heat equation is defined on $\mathbb{R}$, but I wanna se the fundamental solution in case we have boundary conditions.

Answer (score 0):

Let $u(t,x)=T(t)X(x)$ ,

Then $T'(t)X(x)-\epsilon T(t)X''(x)=0$

$T'(t)X(x)=\epsilon T(t)X''(x)$

$\dfrac{T'(t)}{\epsilon T(t)}=\dfrac{X''(x)}{X(x)}=-s^2$

$\begin{cases}\dfrac{T'(t)}{\epsilon T(t)}=-s^2\\X''(x)+s^2X(x)=0\end{cases}$

$\begin{cases}T(t)=c_3(s)e^{-\epsilon ts^2}\\X(x)=\begin{cases}c_1(s)\sin xs+c_2(s)\cos xs&\text{when}~s\neq0\\c_1x+c_2&\text{when}~s=0\end{cases}\end{cases}$

$\therefore u(t,x)=\int_0^\infty C_1(s)e^{-\epsilon ts^2}\sin xs~ds+\int_0^\infty C_2(s)e^{-\epsilon ts^2}\cos xs~ds$

$u(t,0)=1$ :

$\int_0^\infty C_2(s)e^{-\epsilon ts^2}~ds=T_0$

$C_2(s)=\delta(s)$

$\therefore u(t,x)=\int_0^\infty C_1(s)e^{-\epsilon ts^2}\sin xs~ds+\int_0^\infty \delta(s)e^{-\epsilon ts^2}\cos xs~ds$

$u(t,x)=\int_0^\infty C_1(s)e^{-\epsilon ts^2}\sin xs~ds+1$

$u(0,x)=e^\frac{x}{2\epsilon}$ :

$\int_0^\infty C_1(s)\sin xs~ds+1=e^\frac{x}{2\epsilon}$

$\mathcal{F}_{s,s\to x}\{C_1(s)\}=e^\frac{x}{2\epsilon}-1$

$C_1(s)=\mathcal{F}^{-1}_{s,x\to s}\{e^\frac{x}{2\epsilon}-1\}=\dfrac{8\epsilon^2s}{\pi(4\epsilon^2s^2+1)}-\dfrac{2}{\pi s}$ (according to  http://eqworld.ipmnet.ru/en/auxiliary/inttrans/FourSin2.pdf)

$\therefore u(t,x)=\dfrac{8\epsilon^2}{\pi}\int_0^\infty\dfrac{se^{-\epsilon ts^2}\sin xs}{4\epsilon^2s^2+1}~ds-\dfrac{2}{\pi}\int_0^\infty\dfrac{e^{-\epsilon ts^2}\sin xs}{s}~ds+1$

Comment: yes but this only works if we suppose that the solution $u$ is a Multiplicatively separable function.